# How to send data between caller and receiver in PeerJS?

Tags: meteor, webrtc, peerjs

I am building audio calling app and I am struggling to send data between the call receiver to the caller. Here is my code (In the call receiver):

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
peer.on('call', function(call) {

   console.log("call.peer: " + call.peer)
   conn = peer.connect(call.peer)

   bootbox.dialog({
     className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
     closeButton: false,
     animate: true,
     title: 'Call Recieved',
     message: "Accept or Decline",
     onEscape: null,
     buttons: {
       pickup: {
         label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Answer",
         className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
         callback: function(){
           conn.send('ACCEPT') // send Accept to the caller
           return false
         }      
      },
      hangup: {
        label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Decline",
        className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
        callback: function(){
          conn.send('DECLINED') // Send Decline to the caller
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

With the above code, when I make the call, dialog appears and when I press one of the options, data should be sent to the caller.

Here is the caller code, who receives the above sent data:

```js
peer.on('open', function () {
  Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { 'profile.peerId': peer.id } })
  console.log(Meteor.user().profile.peerId);
  peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on('data', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Nothing is printed to the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The connection event isn't important. You want to listen to the `call` event like this

```
    peer.on('call', function (incomingCall) {
```

Hopefully that will work better for you.

I wouldn't update the user record with the peerId, Meteor don't recommend using it, as the authentication system also writes to it. I have used dburles:presence successfully, and in fact passed the presence id to peerjs to use (rather than letting peerjs allocate one)